# How can I modify wp_get_archives() to not use archive.php template?

Tags: archives, template-hierarchy

If using `wp_get_archives()` or another query to display a year/month archive, the links for the months requires the `archive.php` template.

Is there a function which can enable a different template to be used?

Comment: Did you look to `template_redirect` action to load another template base on the query ?

Comment: @Benoti ... Thanks. I wasn't aware of it. A quick look suggests it'll do what I want.

Comment: use `template_include`, not `template_redirect`.